# First Image not being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have the following code snippet which is called on the success of the image uploading procedure.

```
success(data){
      $avatar.attr('src', "/images/common/loading.gif");
      $avatar.attr('src',  data.url);
}
```

Here `$avatar` is the container for an image tag. The idea is to load this image with `loading.gif` until `data.url` is loaded successfully. Here `data.url` may contain a large size image which takes long time to load.

The problem is `loading.gif` is never loaded to the image container until I use `setTimeOut` as:

```
success(data){
      $avatar.attr('src', "/images/common/loading.gif");
      setTimeOut(function(){
            $avatar.attr('src', data.url);
      },100);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me some different approach rather than to use `setTimeOut`?

Answer (score 1):

Showing uploaded image is more important than showing `loader` image But if you are doing it your way, go with the `onload-event`.

Also listen `onerror` event if `loader` image fails, or else `avatar` image will never get loaded!

```js
success(data) {
  var loader = new Image();
  var loadMainImage = function() {
    var mainImage = new Image();
    mainImage.onload = function() { //avatar is loaded!
      $avatar.attr('src', this.src);
    }
    mainImage.src = data.url;
  }
  loader.onload = function() { //loader is loaded!
    $avatar.attr('src', this.src);
    loadMainImage();
  };
  loader.onerror = mainImage; //loader is failed!
  loader.src = "/images/common/loading.gif";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) to handle async promises

Comment: sorry guys my reputation are less so that's why I am posting it as an answer.